# How can I setup my nextjs app to run on EC2 as it's only running on localhost?

Tags: amazon-ec2, next.js

I would like to make my nextjs app run on an EC2 instance (ubuntu 18.04).

However, when I `sudo npm start`, it's then running on localhost, and I don't know how to make it accessible from outside. I tried to access the IP given by AWS and to add the port (:3000), without success.

Would you have an idea of how I must setup this app to be accessible ? What did I miss ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found out

Localhost is not the problem, it was that **the ports are not open by default** on EC2 instances.

By adding a Security Group and opening the ports I needed (http for 80, https 443, ssh with 22, and 3000 for the test) it worked out.